# Issue with Dynamic Form Arrays and While Loops

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

I am having trouble getting data entered into a dynamic form to return properly. I can't tell if this is a javascript or PHP issue.

My javascript:

```
    <script>
      function displayResult()
    {
        var table=document.getElementById("EquipTable");
        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='EquipName[]' id='EquipName' size='40' />";
        cell2.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='Location[]' id='Location' size='10' />";
        cell3.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='Date[]' id='Date' size='10' />";
    }
    </script>
```

My form:

```
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="equipaddsubmit.php">

    <table id="EquipTable">
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">Item Name</strong></td>
        <td width="25%">Location</strong></td>
        <td width="25%">Date Purchased</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
           <input type="text" name="EquipName[]" id="EquipName" size="40" />
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
           <input type="text" name="Location[]" id="Location" size="10" />
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
           <input type="text" name="Date[]" id="Date" size="10" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button>
    <p><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

My PHP on the new page:

```php
    $equip = (array) $_POST["EquipName"];
    $location = (array) $_POST["Location"];
    $date = (array) $_POST["Date"];
    $no_items = count($_POST['EquipName'])-1;
    $num=0;
    while($num<=$no_items)
      {
      $equip[$num]=$equip[$num];
      $location[$num]=$location[$num];
      $date[$num]=$date[$num];

    echo "Row" . $num . " ";
    echo $equip[$num] . " " ;
    echo $location[$num] . " ";
    echo $date[$num];
    echo "<br>";
    $num++;
    }
```

With only one row, the data returns correctly. As soon as I have multiple rows, the $equip returns correctly; the others are unpredictable.

I appreciate your assistance!

When I print the array I get the following:

```php
Array ( 
 [EquipName] => Array ( [0] =>  Item1 [1] => Item2 )
 [Location] => Loc2 
 [Date] => Array ( [0] => 2013-01-02 ) 
 [button] => Submit 
)

Array ( 
 [EquipName] => Array ( [0] => Item1 [1] => Item2 )
 [Location] => Loc2 
 [Date] => Array ( [0] => 2013-01-02 ) 
 [button] => Submit 
)
```

Comment: First note, not a solution: it is not valid to have more than one element with same ID in HTML.

Comment: Please debug and check what data you are getting there

Comment: print_r your $_POST and show me the response.

Comment: like this print_r($_POST);

Comment: second note: why are you reassigning same value to variables `$equip[$num]=$equip[$num] ...`?

Comment: @user1713438 show me your array. then only we will help you

Comment: code is not easy to read in comment, you should edit the question and add it there.

Comment: use `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';` to print the array in readeble form

Comment: hmmm.. I tested your code and it just works.

Comment: Bansi, how many rows did you insert?

Comment: I tried with 4 rows. and now with 8 rows works for it also.

Comment: Bansi, I don't know what happened. I just copied and pasted the PHP code to a new page, and indeed it works, even with null values interspersed. I don't see a difference (did a code comparison)... perhaps it just took another set of eyes. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: what editor are you using? Netbeans has issue of not saving your code and report as saved. I have noted this on windows machine.